# Setting value of s:hidden before submit

Tags: javascript, struts2

I have an export form wich i can export data from 2 cube. Before form submit i would like set in a hidden field the name of the cube to export but it's always stay null in the action. In the javascript function i add an alert for display the value of the hidden file, and it's good. But in the action it's null value.

JSP file :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags"%>

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="<s:url value="/css/jquery.multiselect.css"/>" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="<s:url value="/css/jquery.multiselect.filter.css"/>"
    type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="<s:url value="/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"/>"
    type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<s:url value="/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" />"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<s:url value="/js/jquery-ui.min.js" />"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<s:url value="/js/jquery.multiselect.min.js" />"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<s:url value="/js/jquery.multiselect.filter.js" />"></script>


<script language="javascript">
    function selectionCube(cubeSelected) {
        document.getElementById('cubeType').value = cubeSelected;
        document.getElementById('exportFormStep1').submit();
    }
</script>

<s:form id="exportFormStep1"
    action="exportPdfValidationPerimeterReport.do" name="exportStep1Form"
    theme="simple">

    <s:hidden id="cubeType" name="%{cubeSelected}"></s:hidden>


    <div class="contentTable">

        <div class="bloc_action">
            <input class="btn_action_right" type="button"
                onclick="selectionCube('CUBE_1');"
                value="Cube 1" />

            <input class="btn_action_right" type="button"
                onclick="selectionCube('CUBE_2');"
                value="Cube 2" />
        </div>

    </div>

</s:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using an `OGNL` expression when setting the name of the hidden field? Now, the name of this hidden field is the value of the `cubeSelected` field.
The name of its should be set explicity:

```
<s:hidden id="cubeType" name="cubeSelected"/>
```